# Manager application to check the state of another application

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a windows manager application where I need to allow user to run new instances of another windows application. This manager application should show whether the other application is running if not then allow to run them. If the other application closes or crashes manager application should show that the other application is shutdown.

What is the best way to go about this. Mutex locks, polling, events

Comment: Hi there! Your question is too broad. Here, on stackoverflow, we dealing with coding issues, so if you have a problem with your code (exceptions, unpredictable behavior, etc.) - edit your question or ask another one. You may also find this link useful: [ask]

Answer (score 1):

use **System.Diagnostics.Process** to create new application instances and check HasExited property or listen **Exited** event.